# jQuery accordion menu subitem error--white screen

Tags: jquery, vue.js, laravel-7

I've got a Laravel 7 site with Vue and bootstrap and I have a page with a jquery accordion menu on it. When you click on one of the expandable

it displays a white screen even though the HTML source exists in the background...help?

https://dev8.oddballsinvitations.net/category

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your click event is triggering a "fadeOut" class being applied to your html body tag instead of targeting the accordion div.

Screenshot

https://paste.pics/DV1C4

Here's what your accordion html should look like from bootstrap 5.0 documentation.

````
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>```
````